# A question on a derivation from Hajek's book.

Tags: probability, inequality, convexity-inequality

Concerning this draft here:
http://hajek.ece.illinois.edu/Papers/randomprocJuly14.pdf
on page 71 in the proof of Proposition 2.17, the inequalities (2.8) and (2.9) I don't understand how to derive these two inequalities.

For the first inequality it should follow from the convexity of $f$, but then I need to find a suitable form for the definition of convexity.
But I don't see how exactly.

Can you help here?

Thanks!

P.S
As I was requested in the comments.
We assume that $f$ is convex, that $h>0$ is small enough such that: $s<s+h<t<t+h$, and the inequalities:
$$(2.8)\ \ f(s+h)(t-s+h)\le (t-s)f(s)+hf(t+h)$$
$$(2.9)\ \ f(t)(t-s+h)\le hf(s)+(t-s)f(t+h)$$

Comment: please enter the inequalities you are interested in so question stands on its own. links disappear. also there is trust involved in clicking on a link

Comment: By "71" you mean "61", right?

Comment: @kimchilover yes. In acrobat reader it's 71 in the book it's 61. Thanks!

Comment: @kodlu will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you agree that if $a<b<c$ (that is, $b$ is *between* $a$ and $c$) then $$b=\lambda a+\left(1-\lambda\right)c$$ for some $\lambda\in(0,1)$. $\lambda$ is the coefficient of *betweenness* that we can compute explicitly: since
\begin{align}
b&=\lambda a+\left(1-\lambda\right)c\\&=\left(a-c\right)\lambda+c
\end{align}
it follows that
\begin{align}
\lambda&=\frac{b-c}{a-c}=\frac{c-b}{c-a}\\1-\lambda&=\frac{b-a}{c-a}
\end{align}

Then we can just substitute and apply the definition of convexity:

\begin{align}
f(b)&=f\left(\lambda a+\left(1-\lambda\right)c\right)\\&\le\lambda f(a)+\left(1-\lambda\right)f(c)\\&=\frac{c-b}{c-a}f(a)+\frac{b-a}{c-a}f(c)
\end{align}

Multiplying by the (positive) denominator $c-a$, we get $$\left(c-a\right)f(b)\le(c-b)f(a)+(b-a)f(c).$$

Take $s < s+h < t+h$ for $a<b<c$ and you'll get 2.8.
Take $s < t   < t+h$ for $a<b<c$ and you'll get 2.9.